# CE1.9.2.4 - Custom Module calling 3rd Party API

Tags: magento-1.9, module, controllers, custom, ce-1.9.2.4

I am creating a module that exposes a form for customers to fill in. Upon submission, an ajax request request is made to a PHP script which calls the API.

Now I have already tested this in a separate simple site consisting of just an HTML page (with the form and Javascript) and a PHP file with the function.

As I'm still learning module development in Magento, I'd like to know where my PHP function should go and how to call it (What would be the URL to call)? My first guess is that I need to create a controller with a custom method.

Anyway, here is my PHP function and corresponding Javascript:

Thank you

### submit.php

```
<?php

function is_ajax() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function subscribe() {
  if (is_ajax()) {
    $fieldData = array(
      'api_key'    => '99999999999',
      'email'      => $_POST['email'],
      'properties' => json_encode(array(
        '$first_name' => $_POST['firstname'],
        '$last_name' => $_POST['lastname']
      ))
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://somesite.com/api/v1/subscribe");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldData);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $server_output;
    // echo json_encode($server_output);
    // echo json_encode($fieldData);
  }
}

?>
```

### _index.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testform').submit(function(event) {
    var formData = {
      'email'     : $('input#email').val(),
      'firstname' : $('input#firstname').val(),
      'lastname'  : $('input#lastname').val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'submit.php/subscribe',
      data: formData,
      encode: true,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(data));
      },
      error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need a small module for that.

First create `app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then create `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <module>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Vendor_Module</module>
                    <frontName>module</frontName>
                </args>
            </module>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <module>
                    <file>vendor/module.xml</file>
                </module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now let's create the controller in `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/controllers/IndexController.php` :

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction()
    {       
        $this->loadLayout(); 

        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function submitAction()
    {
        if (_isAjax()) {
            $fieldData = array(
                'api_key'    => '99999999999',
                'email'      => $this->getRequest()->getPost('email'),
                'properties' => Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array(
                    '$first_name' => $this->getRequest()->getPost('firstname'),
                    '$last_name' => $this->getRequest()->getPost(''lastname')
                ))
            );

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://somesite.com/api/v1/subscribe");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldData);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

            curl_close ($ch);

            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($server_output));
        }
    }

    protected function _isAjax() 
    {
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
    }
}
```

Now you need to create the template that will contain your form and your JS.

First you need to create `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/vendor/module.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <module_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="customform" template="vendor/module/form.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </module_index_index>
</layout>
```

And then you can create your template under `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/vendor/module/form.phtml`.

In this file you'll need to add your form code as well as the following modified JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testform').submit(function(event) {
    var formData = {
      'email'     : $('input#email').val(),
      'firstname' : $('input#firstname').val(),
      'lastname'  : $('input#lastname').val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/module/index/submit',
      data: formData,
      encode: true,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(data));
      },
      error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

**Important note:** your form will be accessible by calling `http://yourmagentostore.com/module/index/index` or simply `http://yourmagentostore.com/module`

Comment: Wow! Thanks Raphael. Please allow me a few a minutes to test this out quick

Comment: Amazing! Works beautifully. Got the response I was hoping for:
`"{\"person\": {\"object\": \"person\", \"id\": null, \"email\": \"doe@test.com\"}, \"already_member\": false, \"list\": {\"updated\": \"2016-06-02 10:38:04\", \"person_count\": 2, \"name\": \"Newsletter\", \"created\": \"2016-06-02 10:38:04\", \"list_type\": \"list\", \"id\": \"98744\"}, \"email\": \"doe@test.com\"}"`

Comment: @maGz glad it worked. Feel free to mark your question as answered so it'll benefit for others

Comment: And obviously, if I'm just showing this as a block I can just create a reference to it in my **local.xml** as:

`<reference name="footer">
    <block type="core/template" name="customform" template="vendor/module/form.phtml" />
</reference>`

and then in *app/design/frontend/package/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml*, call it as `$this->getChildHtml('customform');` ... correct?

Comment: 100 points all yours bud. I've definitely now also learned something for the future :)

Comment: @maGz totally correct, just ensure the XML code you pasted in under the `<default>` tag instead of `<module_index_index>` so it displays on all pages

Comment: sorry, meant to say that ... under `<default>`

Comment: so apparently I have to wait 22 hours to award this bounty :$

Comment: @maGz also the native `footer.phtml` calls `$this->getChildHtml();` which automatically renders all the child blocks so depending on how you modified this template you may not have to add `$this->getChildHtml('customform')`

Comment: @maGz no big deal ;) have a nice day

Comment: I notice that Magento only stacks blocks when I specify a `before="XXX"` or `after="XXX"` ... else have to call `getChildHtml('...')` in order to render. FYI, I set a reminder for this time tomorrow to award the bounty. Thanks again man :)

Comment: @maGz should be good for the bounty now ;)

Comment: 100 points for you, sir! :)